# How to verify a string changed from a textbox in listview is not the same as any exiting ones

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ListView` box containing `TextBoxes` that allow users to add and change the content. How do I verify that the content that is changed is not the same as any exiting one in C# behind?

Xaml:

```
<ListView 
   x:Name="_regionQueryListBox" 
   Width="122"  
   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  
   DataContext="{Binding}" 
   IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
   Style="{StaticResource ListViewRegionSelectorStyle}" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Model}" 
   ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
   SelectionChanged="_regionQueryListBox_SelectionChanged">
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
      </Style>
   </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Region" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBox 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                     MaxLength="16"  
                     Width="110" 
                     Margin="-2,0,0,0" 
                     Padding="-2,0,0,0"
                     Text="{Binding Path=RegionName}"/>
               </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         </GridViewColumn>
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide code that you tried so far? Are you using MVVM or just behind the code

Comment: Maybe have a look at Validation in WPF : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15239/Validation-in-Windows-Presentation-Foundation

Comment: I just want to see where is the Model for the RegionName, and how is the DataContext being bound to the ListBox

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is MVVM. I have a validation for adding same item and you can find the Model like below:

```
private void OnQueryCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (Model.Count == 0)
        {
            CurrentRegionViewModel = null;
        }
        if (args.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            RegionQuery addedRegionQuery = args.NewItems.OfType<RegionQuery>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (addedRegionQuery != null)
            {
                string name = addedRegionQuery.RegionName;

                while (Model.Any(q => q.RegionName == name && q != addedRegionQuery))
                {
                    name += "*";
                }

                addedRegionQuery.RegionName = name;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you mean to post this as an answer?  This does not address a change to an existing item.